# Syntax error in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
 #!/bin/sh
df-H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom'| 
awk '{print $5" "$1}' while read output;
do
echo $output
usep=$(echo $output |awk '{print $1}'| cut -d'%'-f1)
partition=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')
if [#usep -ge 80]; then
echo 'running out of space 
\"$partition($usep%)\'on $(hostname)as on $(date)"|mail -s"alert:almost out of disk space $ usep% user@gmail.com);
f1 
Done;
```

while running the script i got  below error.

```
line 6 Unexpected EOF WHILE LOOKING FOR MATCHING '"'
LINE 13 :syntax error : unexpected end of file:
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. May I recommend that you use [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) to check your script for syntax errors?

Comment: Or just look at the syntax highlighting right here, in your question: see how everything is red in the end?

Answer (score 0):

ram, you should carefully check your script. It contains many typos (f1 instead of fi, quote mistakes).

I made this out of  it: sh does not complain about it anymore, you have to check for yourself it is doing what it should:

```
#!/bin/sh
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom'| awk '{print $5" "$1}'
while read output;
do
echo $output
usep=$(echo $output |awk '{print $1}'| cut -d'%'-f1)
partition=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')
if [#usep -ge 80]; then
echo "running out of space \"$partition($usep%)\"on $(hostname)as on $(date)"|mail -s"alert:almost out of disk space $ usep% user@gmail.com);"
fi 
done
```

Comment: How does `sh` not complain? This script will never exit, since you're stuck expecting input for ever and has a syntax error (`if [#usep -ge 80]`)! You need spaces after and before `[` and `]`, and `#usep` is just a string. Please make sure to test your answers before posting.